# How to use CSS timing functions to animate an arc?

Tags: css, animation, transition

I would like to use CSS only to animate an object to move in an arc and ***follow the same path on the way back***.

Here is what I have so far (simplified). [Full JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gbng5oyh/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="outer">
       <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.outer { transition: all 1.5s ease; }
.inner { transition: all 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.590, 0.460, 1.005); }

.container:hover .outer { transform: translateY(180px); }
.container:hover .inner { transform: translateX(180px); }
```

As you can see the first part is working how I want it. It moves down in a **convex outer arc**. But when it comes back in, it's coming back in a **convex inner arc**. How can I get it to return on the same path using only CSS?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gbng5oyh/5/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try rotating a vertical element using `rotateZ` instead, similar to the solution below. Note the need to set the `top` to `-20px` in order to keep the rotated element within the boundaries of the container, as well as `transform-origin` used to set the rotation point to the bottom left corner of the element.

```css
.container { 
  font-size: 0;
  height: 180px;
  width: 180px; 
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}

.outer {
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 1.5s cubic-bezier(0, .59, .46, 1);

  /* border added to better visualize behaviour */
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container:hover .outer {
  /* -2px added because of blue border */
  /* without the border this would be the same as -1*(.inner's width) */
  top: -22px;
  transform: rotateZ(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It has the advantage that it actually follows an arc, while the original transition did not.